# How to access the last element in a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Let us consider the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I want to access the first element in pandas series `df['col1']`, I can simply go `df['col1'][0]`.

But how can I access the *last* element in this series?
I have tried `df['col1'][-1]` which returns the following error:

> KeyError: -1L

I know that I could go for something like `df['col1'][len(df)-1]` but why is reverse indexing impossible here?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

For select last value need [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html), because `df['col1']` return `Series`:

```
print (df['col1'].iloc[-1])
3
print (df['col1'].iat[-1])
3
```

Or convert Series to numpy array and select last:

```
print (df['col1'].values[-1])
3
```

Or use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) - but is necessary position of column by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('col1')])
3
print (df.iat[-1, df.columns.get_loc('col1')])
3
```

Or is possible use last value of index (necessary not duplicated) and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc[df.index[-1], 'col1'])
3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jezrael! `print (df['col1'].iloc[-1])` will do the trick.

Comment: from the question `df` is a `Dataframe`, not `Series`. What adjustment to attain the same using `Series`?

Comment: @Gathide Use `s=pd. Series()` then instead `df['col1']` use `s`

Comment: @jezrael `s=pd.Series(data=d)`, then `s.iloc[-1]` gives `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `[3,5]` - the last values for each `col`.

Comment: @Gathide then use `s.str[-1]`

Comment: @jezrael, Thanks, `.str` does it. I initially feared carrying out computations (additions, averages etc) in strings.

Answer (score 16):

To take last through values is the most quick way:

```
%timeit df['code'].values[-1].   )
```

> 5.58 µs ± 985 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%timeit df.loc[df.index[-1], 'code']
```

> 12 µs ± 2.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%timeit df['code'].iat[-1]
```

> 5.71 µs ± 896 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%timeit df['code'].tail(1).item()
```

> 36 µs ± 3.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

```
%timeit df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('code')]
```

> 33.7 µs ± 5.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

```
%timeit df['code'].iloc[-1]
```

> 8.08 µs ± 496 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `tail`:

```
print(df['col1'].tail(1).item())
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: I must say that I find `print (df['col1'].iloc[-1])` more intuitive but thanks for bringing up this solution, U9-Forward!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [`take`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.take.html):

```
In [6]: df['col1'].take([-1]).item()
Out[6]: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @rachwa. I did not know about the `take` function; I am sure that it will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
df.iloc[-1, 0]
```