# Selecting by index -1 in a df column / time series throws error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, numpy-slicing

Let's assume we have a simple dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[10,20,30]})
```

Then I can select elements like this

`df.col2[0]` or `df.col2[1]`

But if I want to select the last element with `df.col2[-1]` it results in the error message:

```
KeyError: -1
```

I know that there are workarounds to that. I could do for example `df.col2[len(df)-1]` or `df.iloc[-1,1]`. But why wouldn't be the much simpler version of indexing directly by `-1` be allowed? Am I maybe missing another simple selection way for `-1`? Tnx

Comment: When using a Python list, ```my_list[-1]``` accesses the last item. However, ```df.col2``` is not a Python list, but a Pandas Series. If you want to access the last item, you can first convert it to a list and access it via [-1], or other means as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288949/how-to-access-the-last-element-in-a-pandas-series)

Comment: @R.dV Thanks, this helps a little bit! But do you know what is the motivation behind making `df.col2[1]` possible, but not `df.col2[-1]`. Some programming paradigm? Or something about the way python should work? Is there some deeper meaning?

Comment: A list is native to Python, Pandas and all its features are not. I guess the developers behind Pandas have a reason for it, but I could only guess what that is. In my understanding though, a Pandas Series is not a list, but more a dictionary, so it uses keys. While a list[1] accesses the item at index 1, Series[1] accesses the item at key 1, which is a subtle difference. dm2's answer explains this more detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index labels of your DataFrame are [0,1,2]. Your code `df.col2[1]` is an equivalent of using a loc function as `df['col2'].loc[1]`(or `df.col2.loc[1]`). You can see that you index does not contain a label '-1' (which is why you get the KeyError).

For positional indexing you need to use an iloc function (which you can use on Pandas Series as well as DataFrame), so you could do `df['col2'].iloc[-1]` (or `df.col2.iloc[-1]`).

As you can see, you can use both label based ('col2') and position based (-1) indexing together, you don't need to choose one or another as `df.iloc[-1,1]` or `df.col2[len(df)-1]` (which would be equivalent to `df.loc[lend(df)-1,'col2']`)

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know all the alternatives and the slicing! But do you know what is the motivation behind making `df.col2[1]` possible, but not `df.col2[-1]`. Some programming paradigm? Or something about the way python should work? Is there some deeper meaning?

Comment: Afaik it's just that for pandas `df[col][index]` is equivalent to label indexing (i.e. `df.loc[index_label, column_label]` and you can't use a non existing label (so, if your DataFrame has a row labeled -1, you COULD use df.col2[-1] to get that row), and for positional inexing, you need to specify to use `.iloc`. I guess pandas gives priority to label based indexing rather than positional indexing. Seeing as neither lists nor numpy arrays have labels attached to their rows and columns, positional indexing is the default for them. (new comment to correct .loc to .iloc)